# Flutter Google Map rounded image marker not align in the center

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I recently worked the the google maps with flutter.

i created the marker to indicate the users current location. and added three circles in to indicate the accuracy of the Google map. And the marker image is round shaped. and it is bottom aligned.

But i need the center alignment of the marker.
Like this

[image: The Expected Design]

The Output of my code

[image: The Output]

The function for getting user location and set marker and circles

```
  onInitFunc() async {
    locationicon = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(
        await getBytesFromAsset('assets/icons/map-store.png'));
    mylocationicon = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(
      await getBytesFromAsset('assets/images/avatar.png'),
    );
    setState(() {
      isIconsUpdated = true;
    });
    var _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }
    currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
    await setMarketsOfMyLocation();
    locationSubscription = location.onLocationChanged.listen((location) async {
      currentLocation = location;
      await setMarketsOfMyLocation();
      setState(() {});
    });
    setState(() {});
  }

  setMarketsOfMyLocation() async {
    markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: const MarkerId('myPosition'),
        position: LatLng(
          currentLocation!.latitude!,
          currentLocation!.longitude!,
        ),
        flat: true,
        icon: mylocationicon,
        onTap: () {
          mapController.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
              CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(
                  currentLocation!.latitude!,
                  currentLocation!.longitude!,
                ),
                zoom: 15,
              ),
            ),
          );
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
    circles = {
      Circle(
        circleId: const CircleId('myPosition1'),
        center: LatLng(
          currentLocation!.latitude!,
          currentLocation!.longitude!,
        ),
        radius: 100,
        fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
        strokeWidth: 0,
      ),
      Circle(
        circleId: const CircleId('myPosition2'),
        center: LatLng(
          currentLocation!.latitude!,
          currentLocation!.longitude!,
        ),
        radius: 200,
        fillColor: const Color(0xFFFAAB1B).withOpacity(0.1),
        strokeWidth: 0,
      ),
      Circle(
        circleId: const CircleId('myPosition3'),
        center: LatLng(
          currentLocation!.latitude!,
          currentLocation!.longitude!,
        ),
        radius: 300,
        fillColor: const Color(0xFFFAAB1B).withOpacity(0.05),
        strokeWidth: 0,
      ),
    };
    setState(() {});
  }
```

The widget code of google map

```
SizedBox(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  child: GoogleMap(
    circles: circles,
    mapToolbarEnabled: false,
    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
    myLocationEnabled: false,
    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
      zoom: 10,
      target: LatLng(
        // bangalore
        currentLocation.runtimeType == Null
            ? 12.9716
            : currentLocation!.latitude!,
        currentLocation.runtimeType == Null
            ? 77.5946
            : currentLocation!.longitude!,
      ),
    ),
    onTap: (position) {
      _customInfoWindowController.hideInfoWindow();
      setState(() {
        currentStore = null;
      });
      mapController.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bounds(markers)!, 50),
      );
    },
    onCameraMove: (position) {
      _customInfoWindowController.onCameraMove();
    },
    mapType: MapType.normal,
    markers: markers,
    onMapCreated: onMapcreated,
    compassEnabled: true,
    zoomControlsEnabled: false,
  ),
),
```

Comment: tried to change the [anchor](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_map/latest/flutter_map.plugin_api/Marker/anchor.html)?

Comment: Thanks man. After researching with this anchor attribute. I got the answer.